# How can I extract RDFa from HTML using PHP or Java?

Tags: java, php, html, rdf, rdfa

I am a newbie, trying to learn about RDF, RDFa and stuffs related to it since few days..

My question is, consider following HTML + RDFa code .. is it possible to extract the RDF part separately? if so could you please demonstrate simple code snippet (PHP or Java)..

i have heard Jena could be used, but couldn't find a tutorial which explains this. So if it is possible with Jena could anyone post some code snippet please..

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:foaf="http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/"
xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
version="XHTML+RDFa 1.0" xml:lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>John's Home Page</title>
    <base href="http://example.org/john-d/" />
    <meta property="dc:creator" content="Jonathan Doe" />
    <link rel="foaf:primaryTopic" href="http://example.org/john-d/#me" />
  </head>
  <body about="http://example.org/john-d/#me">
    <h1>John's Home Page</h1>
    <p>My name is <span property="foaf:nick">John D</span> and I like
      <a href="http://www.neubauten.org/" rel="foaf:interest"
        xml:lang="de">Einstürzende Neubauten</a>.
    </p>
    <p>
      My <span rel="foaf:interest" resource="urn:ISBN:0752820907">favorite
      book is the inspiring <span about="urn:ISBN:0752820907"><cite
      property="dc:title">Weaving the Web</cite> by
      <span property="dc:creator">Tim Berners-Lee</span></span>
     </span>
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can extract the RDF from the pages containing RDFa markup, and once extracted, you can put it into a local RDF triplestore if you want to do some stuff w/ that data alone, or you could insert it into a global triplestore and be able to query it alongside existing RDF data.

[Here](https://web.archive.org/web/20130907041014/http://answers.semanticweb.com/questions/1493/what-is-the-best-java-rdfa-parser) is a relevant discussion on Java RDFa parsers.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at Damian's [java-rdfa](http://github.com/shellac/java-rdfa). You can use it with [Apache Jena](http://incubator.apache.org/jena/), here is a snipped of code:

```
Class.forName("net.rootdev.javardfa.RDFaReader");
Model model = ...
model.read(url, "XHTML"); // xml parsing
model.read(other, "HTML"); // html parsing
```

Another option in Java is [Apache Any23](http://incubator.apache.org/any23/).

Comment: Thanks castagna.. This is exactly what i was looking for.. Also there are lot more alternatives present along with what you said, its there in the discussion link provided by Michael..

Comment: Hey i tried following code

    Class.forName("net.rootdev.javardfa.RDFaReader");
    Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
    model.read("file:///C:/sample.html", "GRDDL");
    model.write(System.out, "RDF/XML");

but it gives error : Unhandled exception type ClassNotFoundException HelloRdfWorld.java

could you please help out.. plz..

Comment: Have you seen GRDDL is my answer? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Parsing RDFa in PHP: https://github.com/njh/easyrdf/ (use 0.8 / master branch to have the RDFa parser)

Parsing RDFa in Java: http://semarglproject.org/

Answer (score -5):

You can't separate the RDF from the HTML as the RDF is providing additional information about things in the HTML.

It would be like taking the footnotes and bibliography out of a book and throwing the book away: Mostly meaningless.

Comment: Hey thanks for the quick reply... But what my question is that is it possible  to extract RDFa and use it for some other processing.. Say i have 10 related HTML +RDFa pages, i want to extract a copy of RDFa (not Seperate/Delete)  from all these pages, combine it and use it for further processing at server side (Eg. say i want to insert into a db or execute some query on RDFa etc,..) Is this possible?

Comment: I don't understand how taking the RDF out of the page and putting it in the database doesn't separate the RDF from the data it is describing. Obviously the original HTML+RDFa documents are still intact, but they aren't connected to the database.

Comment: Ok ok.. So it is not possible to get pure list of all triples present in bunch of HTML + RDFa documents? Then what is Jena used for? could you please brief...

Comment: When you have HTML+RDFa part of the tuple is expressed in HTML. The Jena homepage makes no mention of being able to deal with that but talks about dealing with (pure) RDF.

Comment: Initially i checked up this link http://www.w3.org/TR/grddl-primer/ Which says it is possible to get RDF from XHTML..
And then i found this link http://jena.sourceforge.net/grddl/index.html which is the implementation of GRDDL for Jena Framework..